# Swiftでの画像処理について

Tags: swift, php, json

サーバサイドから送られてきた16進数の画像データをSwiftで表示する機能を実装しようとしています。
しかし、現状その16進数表記の画像データをどうやって処理し、画像として表示すればよいのかがわかっていません。
今はサーバサイドからの画像データをJSONで受け取るところまでできています。

```
func downloadBtn(sender :UIButton){

    //create url request
    //set URL
    let urlstr = "http://192.168.33.10/test_app/images/recieveImage"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlstr)!)

    //set method
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    //タスクの生成
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{ data, response, error in
        //succeed post
        if(error == nil){
            let result = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            //結果を出力

　　　　　　　//サーバからのデータをJSONで受け取る
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            let resp = json["resp"].string
            print(resp)
　　　　　　　　/*
　　　　　　　　出力結果が16進数データになっていることを確認
　　　　　　　　*/

            //(1)スペースを削除
            let deleteTarget = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet
            let img_data = resp!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(deleteTarget())
            //print("resp = \(img_data)")

        }else{
            print(error)    
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

(1)では取得したデータが先頭と末尾にスペースがあるので取り除いています。

`img_data`はString型になっていると思うのですが、それをどう処理して画像を表示すればよいのかがわかりません。

なにかありましたら、随時補足いたします。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

64進数での例ですが参考にできると思います。
http://blog.sarabande.jp/post/92097422168